# How to use If-Else statements to filter a table?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below filters the 4th column of `Table1` for any blank cells then deletes those rows if blank.

```
Sub DeleteJob()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Set reference to the sheet and Table.
    Set ws = Sheets("Line Item Summary")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    ws.Activate

    'Clear any existing filters
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    '1. Apply Filter
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=""

    '2. Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '3. Clear Filter
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

When the code is run once, the rows with blanks are all removed and the 4th column is left with cells with values, but an error will pop up because there are no more blank cells to look for/delete. I was thinking of using an "If/Else" statement so if there are blanks then the respective row is deleted otherwise do nothing if all cells in the column have a value. I do not know how to modify the code below to accommodate for this.

```
'2. Delete Rows
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option: use `Application.CountBlank` first before even filtering.

```
If Application.CountBlank(tbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange) = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: I tried it with my code and it seems to work. My understanding is that this will search column 4 before filtering for any non-zero values. If every cell in column 4 has a value then it will exit the macro?

Comment: Looking to open this up again for a quick modification. The column to be filtered have values in _Accounting Format_. As per your suggestion, I would like to search column 4 for any values that are NOT `$-`, i.e. $  145,0450.56. If there is a cell that is `$-` then continue and filter.