# Filter table based on cell value/format

Tags: excel, vba

A slight modification is needed for the code below.
This is based on a previous question I posted [How to use If-Else statements to filter a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793124/how-to-use-if-else-statements-to-filter-a-table/59793147?noredirect=1#comment105863977_59793147)

`Column 14` is to be filtered and has values in Accounting number format. I would like to search `Column 14` for any values that are NOT `$-` , i.e. `$   145,0450.56`. If there is a cell that is `$-` then continue and filter.

I tried using <> as a way to say value that are NOT equal to `$-` but this doesn't work.

```
Sub DeleteJob()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet and Table.
  Set ws = Sheets("Line Item Summary")
  Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
  ws.Activate

  'Clear any existing filters
  tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    With tbl.ListColumns(14)
        If Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange, ">0") + _
           Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange, "<0") = 0 Then
             Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

  'Apply Filter
  tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=""

  'Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  '3Clear Filter
  tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

This is the line I edited:
`If Application.CountBlank(tbl.ListColumns(14).DataBodyRange) = 0 Then Exit Sub`

When I run the code it ignores the non value rows (shown below) and exits the macro half way. The code needs to recognize that there are rows with `$-` and continue with the code to filter.

[image]

Comment: ```Countblank``` returns a number it will never be equal to "$-" and will always exit sub.

Comment: `$-` is just `0`, with the format applied.

Comment: Do you have any blank rows in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$-` is just `0`, formatted.

One option is just to check if you have values not equal to zero:

```
With tbl.ListColumns(14)
    If Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange,">0") + _
       Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange,"<0") = 0 Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

Note that `Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange,"<>0")` would include blank cells, which is why you can use the "long route" as shown above.

**EDIT:** I think I got it backwards:

```
With tbl.ListColumns(14)
    If Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange,"=0") = 0 Then
         Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

Comment: This works great after one run. Once the `0` cells are filtered and deleted the column is left with all values. When I run the macro again the code does not recognize that there are no more `0` cells and will continue to filter then an error pops up.

Comment: I edited the full code in the original question to show the placement of your suggestion

Comment: Maybe you want `If Application.Countif(.DataBodyRange,"=0") = 0 Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: Or even shorter, `Application.CountIf(.DataBodyRange,0) = 0`.